fail2ban iptables rule has no effect for SoftEther VPN ... unless sshd rule is place
I am completely perplexed as to why this doesn't work.
This is my bare iptables ruleset:
# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

My /etc/fail2ban/jail.local:
[softethervpn]

enabled = true
port = 5555
logpath = /path/to/sevpn/sec_*.log
bantime = 2592000       ; ban for 30 days
findtime = 86400        ; look back 1 day
maxretry = 3
banaction = iptables-allports

[sshd]

enabled = true
port    = 22
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
bantime = 2592000       ; ban for 30 days
findtime = 86400        ; look back 1 day
maxretry = 3
banaction = iptables-allports

In /var/log/fail2ban.log, it detects failed auth correctly:
[softethervpn] Found 123.123.123.123 - 2024-07-12 12:13:17
[softethervpn] Found 123.123.123.123 - 2024-07-12 12:13:20
[softethervpn] Found 123.123.123.123 - 2024-07-12 12:13:22
[softethervpn] Ban 123.123.123.123

Then adds the appropriate iptables rules:
Chain f2b-softethervpn (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  123.123.123.123        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

However, the f2b-softethervpn chain has no effect.  I am still able to connect from the banned client IP ... until I trigger a ban on the sshd rule, and iptables f2b rules look like this:
Chain f2b-softethervpn (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  123.123.123.123        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  123.123.123.123        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Then, the client is unable to connect to the VPN or SSH, as expected.
This makes no sense.  The f2b rules are literally identical.  Why don't the softethervpn rules work?

Found the problem, the clue was in the f2b rules inserted at the top of the INPUT chain:
# iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 195 packets, 20594 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    6   710 f2b-softethervpn  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 157K  215M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state ESTABLISHED

Notice it's only blocking UDP at this point, so TCP is still able to connect.  The fix is adding this line to the jail in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local:
action = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s-tcp, actionname=%(__name__)s-tcp, protocol="tcp", port="%(port)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
         %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s-udp, actionname=%(__name__)s-udp, protocol="udp", port="%(port)s", chain="%(chain)s"]

Now it bans UDP and TCP:
# iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 237 packets, 24987 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    4   414 f2b-softethervpn-udp  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   73  5552 f2b-softethervpn-tcp  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0    

...

Chain f2b-softethervpn-tcp (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       123.123.123.123      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   73  5552 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain f2b-softethervpn-udp (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       123.123.123.123      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    4   414 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

EDIT
Actually, that can be cleaned up a bit with:
%(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, actionname=%(__name__)s, protocol="all", port="%(port)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
Then it just creates a single rule/ruleset to capture TCP+UDP.
